# How to get products with their groups and subgroups in same query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am struggling with writing query that will return an products, their groups and parent of their group.

Here is my database schema:

[image]

One product will have only 1 group which is directly related to him, and that group can have only 1 parent group which is directly related to that group. So for example my structure looks like this:

```
Drinks

Alcohol drinks

           Vodka
           Jack Daniels

Non alcohol drinks

           Pepsi
           Juice
```

So in example above:

- Pepsi has directly related group : Non alcohol drinks

and the parent group of that group is `Drinks`.

That means Id of Pepsi will be inserted into table `ArticleGroups` also directly related Group will be inserted there in same row - GroupId, and so that means I need to join pepsi's GroupId with table Groups where is pepsi's parent group so I can get both groups (Non alcohol drinks and Drinks).

This is what I've written so far but I'm not sure if this can works like this, this is confusing me really...

```
Select ---
From Articles as T1 
Join ArticleGroups as T2 on T1.ArticleId = T2.ArticleId
Join Groups as T3 on T2.GroupId = T3.GroupId 
Join Groups as T4 on T3.ParentId = T4.GroupId
```

This query I wrote is confusing me, because it looks like ..

Select something from Articles join ArticlesGroups to get directly related group to Article, after that join to Groups to get Title and other information of that directly related group, and after that I should join again to Groups because in same table as a parentId is main group of article's group..

This is confusing me really ..

In my Select I need to get Article, His directly related group like (Non alcohol drinks) and parent of Non alcohol drinks, which is Drinks... so many join on same table confusing me..

Expected results should look like this:

[image]

As you can see guys I need to get products title from Article table, also I need to get product's group from table articlegroups joined to groups, and I also need to get parent group of article's group which is in table groups..

**IMPORTANT:** Group Drinks is as you can see parent group of Non-alcohol drinks and Alcohol drinks, it's defined in table Groups..

Any kind of help would be great,

Thanks !

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: @D-Shih I just posted how expected results should look like... check for my edit of bottom of my post please.. And thanks for reply

Comment: Your database design has imperfections. You need to join group twice because of the 'parent group' being stored in the group table...

Comment: Your query seems to be correct. There is nothing wrong with joining a table with itself and necessary whenever you have parent child relationships. Can you post the results you are getting with this query? It is possible that data issues can cause too many rows (one to one relationships not enforced) or too few rows (missing relationships)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is correct.  If you used better table aliases, perhaps you would see it better:

```
Select a.*, g.name as subgroup, gp.name as parent_group
From Articles a left join
     ArticleGroups ag
     on ag.ArticleId = a.ArticleId left join
     groups g   -- lowest level group ("subgroup")
     on ag.GroupId = g.GroupId left join
     Groups gp  -- parent group
     on gp.GroupId = g.ParentId ;
```

I replaced the inner joins with outer joins, so the query will return all articles, even those with no groups or parent groups.

The data structure is ok, but it can get cumbersome if groups start to have more of a hierarchy

Comment: thx for reply, can you give me some tip, how to learn sql from the bottom, without missing a lot, I want to learn Sql really, writing a queries is so powerful and cool thing